# How to find the IP address of the Server inside the EJB

Tags: java, ip, ejb, weblogic, cluster-computing

I have deployed EJB application in weblogic cluster  which consist of 2 managed servers. I need to track witch physical server is  processing the each and every request from the remote client. So I need to print server Ip inside EJB method. Please advice me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can help you:

```
System.out.println("Server-IP:" +  java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress());
System.out.println("Host:" + java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost());
```

Answer (score 2):

We had somewhat similar requirement in our project.
We wanted to print the Managed Server Instance Name in logs which has processed the JMS message.
We did it in following way -

```
System.getProperty("weblogic.Name");
```